# Проблем с сортировкой postgresql

Tags: postgresql, сортировка

Вот такой запрос `SELECT id_subject, info::json->>'price' FROM subject ORDER BY info::json->>'price' ASC;` приводит к такому выводу. Тут явно проблемы с сортировкой

```
id_subject | ?column? 
------------+----------
        356 | 101.5
        217 | 102.04
        338 | 102.5
        362 | 102.7
        219 | 103.22
        228 | 11.62
        317 | 126.8
        319 | 130.8
        191 | 13.63
        316 | 141.1
        215 | 159.79
        231 | 172.42
        298 | 177.5
        239 | 179.48
        297 | 186.7
```

Как пофиксить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `jsonb` формате, у вас все строки, вот вам `price` был отсортирован как строка, надо привести их числу

```
SELECT id_subject, info::json->>'price' FROM subject ORDER BY (info::json->>'price')::float ASC;
```